# Adding angular.module(['nghandsontable']) now my ui-select are gone

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a issues when i add this line of code

```
var mainApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngHandsontable']);
```

to my controller all my dropdowns (ui-select) disappear.

My controller looks like this

```
mainApp.controller("fixturesController", ["$scope", "$http", "$q", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
```

Does anyone know why it would break all my ui-select's?

Comment: might wanna inject the `ui.select` module

Comment: when you **add** `var mainApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngHandsontable']);`, your code **breaks**?  Thas seems odd, since `angular.module` is required for an app to load... Did you remove a different line with `angular.module` and replace it with this?  or do you already have another line with `angular.module` in another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the fix

`var mainApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngHandsontable','ui.select']);`